# Multiple OS Unit Testing in one file - Is it possible?

Tags: c++, unit-testing

I need to do something like this:

```
void Test::testUnitTest() {
#define OS_MACOSX 1
    performUnitTest();
#undef OS_MACOSX
    performUnitTest();
}

void Test::performUnitTest() {
    CefKeyEvent event;
    event.modifiers = CTRL;
    event.windows_key_code = KeyboardHander::KeyCodeC;
#ifdef OS_MACOSX
    fructose_assert(1==2);
    event.modifiers = COMMAND;
#endif
    fructose_assert(handler.get()->IsCopyRequest(event));
}
```

...

```
bool RealClass::IsCopyRequest(const CefKeyEvent& event) {
#ifdef OS_MACOSX
    return IsCOMMANDDown(event.modifiers) && event.character == 'c';
#else
    return isCTRLDown(event.modifiers) && event.character == 'c';
#endif
}
```

When `testUnitTest()` is called, the fructose_assert(1==2)in `performUnitTest()` is never called. In the actual test, it's always calling the isCTRLDown() method. Which makes sense with a preprocessor directive. Question is, how to make this actually work?

Comment: _in the real code, `performUnitTest()` would call methods on classes that also use `#ifdef OS_MACOSX` in their logic_ Provide a sample that gets more close to your _real code_ please!

Comment: In you build script you will define a macro depending on the platform where you compile it. So the `OS_MACOSX` should be defined by the buildscript. And in your code (including the unit test)  you would then test if this macro was set. `#ifdef OS_MACOSX`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The preprocessor macros `#define` are... preprocessor macros. It means they are handled before the compiler is called. The preprocessor processes the files, and then send them to the compiler.

I you write

```
#define OS_MACOSX 1
     #ifdef OS_MACOSX
          performUnitTest();
     #endif
#undef OS_MACOSX
```

The compiler receives nothing.

But when you do

```
#define OS_MACOSX 1
    performUnitTest();
#undef OS_MACOSX
```

That does not call the method with OS_MACOSX set but just roughly does nothing special, the compiler receives performUnitTest();

It would work if performUnitTest was a macro itself, though that's probably a bad idea.

If you use gcc, you can use the `-save-temps` option and look at the `.i` file, that's the output of the preprocessor.

Could you pass a parameter to the test function like this:

```
void Test::testUnitTest() {
    performUnitTest(true);
    performUnitTest(false);
}

void Test::performUnitTest(bool is_mac_os) {
    CefKeyEvent event;
    event.modifiers = CTRL;
    event.windows_key_code = KeyboardHander::KeyCodeC;
    if (is_mac_os) {
        fructose_assert(1==2);
        event.modifiers = COMMAND;
    }
    fructose_assert(handler.get()->IsCopyRequest(is_mac_os, event));
}

...

bool RealClass::IsCopyRequest(bool is_mac_os, const CefKeyEvent& event) {
    if (is_mac_os) {
        return IsCOMMANDDown(event.modifiers) && event.character == 'c';
    } else {
        return isCTRLDown(event.modifiers) && event.character == 'c';
    }
}
```

But I don't feel this is what you want.
If your code is platform dependent (`IsCopyRequest` sounds to be), it means you want a unit test to be run on MacOs and another on another OS.
So you can write

```
void Test::testUnitTest() {
    performUnitTest();
}

void Test::performUnitTest() {
    CefKeyEvent event;
    event.modifiers = CTRL;
    event.windows_key_code = KeyboardHander::KeyCodeC;
#ifdef OS_MACOSX
    fructose_assert(1==2);
    event.modifiers = COMMAND;
#endif
    fructose_assert(handler.get()->IsCopyRequest(is_mac_os, event));
}
```

Then you compile this on MacOS (with `OS_MACOSX` defined) and run it.
And then you compile this on another os (without `OS_MACOSX` defined) and run it.

Comment: Thanks Nicolas. I could pass an argument. What would you suggest?

Comment: I edited my reply to answer, I hope that makes sense.